# C# DataGrid character encoding

Tags: c#, winforms, encoding

My application pulls data from a file, splits it up to several `DataTable`s and then shows the data in a `DataGrid` according to a selection. The problem is, that when I show it in the datagrid, special characters seem to use the wrong encoding, I get the following sign: `�`.

This is how I get the file data:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@filename, true))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        // split the data in the file on ;
        var line = reader.ReadLine().Split(';');

        // Put the data in an object for the datatable
        object[] row = new object[] { line[0], line[1] };

        // Data will be put in a DataTable without any other conversion
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}

// Create reader from datatable
using (DataTableReader reader = table.CreateDataReader())
{
    // Loop through the table
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // Create new object that will act as a row
        object[] newrow = new object[] { reader[0], reader[1] };

        // Add the row
        dataGrid.Rows.Add(newrow);
    }
}
```

The above code works perfectly, and is simplified. Obviously there is more going on, but nothing that would affect any encoding. I have searched around a bit, but I can't seem to find a solution to this particular issue.

Note: I do not know the file's encoding, and the encoding may vary for each file.

Comment: You should *know* the file's encoding, otherwise you're just guessing

Comment: @w0lf I know, is there a way to find the file encoding then, so I might be able to use it and make sure it shows correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the file's encoding in advance, the best you can do is guess what that encoding is.

I suggest you read this great article: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

It's fun to read and I personally found some valuable information/clarifications in there.

But the main takeaway from the article is this:

> #### It does not make sense to have a string without knowing what encoding it uses.

---

Leaving theory aside, I know in practice it is sometimes impossible to ask a user what is the encoding of the file they just submitted/uploaded.

So, again, the best you can do is guess.

I have dealt with this problem a few times in my career and every time I managed to find a *good enough* encoding guessing algorithm, depending on the nature of the system being developed.

The best thing you can do is grab as many sample files as you can, manually analyze their encodings and see if you can find patterns, such as:

- all users submit files encoded in UTF-8, except users A and B who use ISO-8859-1
- if a file contains a certain byte sequence, it's very likely that it's encoding A, otherwise use default encoding B

Comment: I have found out that almost every file I get will be utf8. Now I know that encoding, how do I make sure the output in the DataGrid is utf8 too? Because that still gives the wrong special signs.